# Flex: binding tab labels to variables

Tags: apache-flex, tabbar, viewstack, bindable

I'm using a custom tabbar with the dataProvider being a viewstack and I'm trying to get the tab labels to update when data in the related container (in the viewstack) updates.

The viewstack's containers are bound to bindable vars, so if a var changes, the data/labels/etc in the container updates, but the tab doesn't.

Is there a way to bind the tab to the same bindable var or do i need to write event handlers (if so, what events)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I have found my answer. I wasn't properly updated the label and other bindable variables that the tab listens to in the container. I added a "propertyChange" event listener to the variable that the container was binding to and had its event handler update the label which in turn updated the tab. all is well.